# OpenCV Merge Mertens taking way more time on C++ as compared to Python

Tags: python, android, c++, opencv

I have implemented an image enhancement technique that uses OpenCV's Merge Mertens. I have coded it in Python and C++. On same set of images of same size and dimensions, Merge Mertens takes less than 2 seconds on Python while taking 11 seconds on C++. I want my C++ code to be faster as I have to deploy it on android devices.

Moreover, I tried to implemented another exposure fusion technique on both Python and C++. Below is my implementation of [Fast Exposure Fusion](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8296679) in Python. In python it takes 2 seconds but when translated to C++, it takes 12 seconds.

```
def merge(pme):

r = 12
eps = 0.25
sig_l = 0.5  
sig_g = 0.2  
sig_d = 0.12 
alpha = 1.1  
W_B = []
W_D = []
B = []
D = []

for img in pme:
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img /= 255

    lum = cv.cvtColor((img), cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    base_img = cv.ximgproc.guidedFilter(lum, lum, r, eps)
    wl = np.divide(np.square(base_img - 0.5), -2*sig_l*sig_l)
    wg = np.square(np.mean(lum) - 0.5) / (-2*sig_g*sig_g)
    wl = np.exp(wl)
    wg = np.exp(wg)
    wb = wl * wg
    W_B.append(wb)
    B.append(base_img)

    detail_img = img - base_img[:,:,None]
    kernel = np.ones((7, 7),np.float32)/49
    conved = cv.filter2D(lum,-1,kernel)
    wd = np.divide(np.square(conved - 0.5), -2*sig_d*sig_d)
    wd = np.exp(wd)
    W_D.append(wd)
    D.append(detail_img)

wb_s = np.sum(W_B, axis=0)+0.01
wd_s = np.sum(W_D, axis=0)+0.01

final = np.zeros(pme[0].shape)
for i in range(len(pme)):
    wb = np.true_divide(W_B[i], wb_s)
    b = B[i]
    wd = np.true_divide(W_D[i], wd_s)                
    d = D[i]
    final += (wb*b)[:,:,None] + (alpha*(wd[:,:,None]*d))

return final
```

Is there any reason why this is happening? How could I achieve same time as Python on C++ as speed is necessary for me as I would be using this code for android.

Edit: Here is the C++ code

```
void expo_fuse(vector<Mat> pme, Mat &res) {
  float r = 12, eps = 0.25, sig_l = 0.5, sig_g = 0.2, sig_d = 0.12, alpha = 1.1;
  vector<Mat> W_B, W_D, B, D;

  for (int i = 0; i < pme.size(); i++) {
      Mat img = pme[i].clone();
      img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC3);
      img = img / 255;
      Mat lum;
      cvtColor(img, lum, COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 1);
      double max_v;
      minMaxIdx(lum, nullptr, &max_v, nullptr, nullptr);

      Mat wl;
      float wg;
      Mat base = guidedFilter(lum, lum, r, eps);
      wl = (base - 0.5).mul(base - 0.5) / (-2 * sig_l*sig_l);
      float m = mean(lum)[0];
      wg = ((m - 0.5)*(m - 0.5)) / (-2 * sig_l*sig_l);
      exp(wl, wl);
      wg = exp(wg);
      W_B.push_back(wl * wg);
      B.push_back(base);

      wl.release();
      cvtColor(base, base, COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

      Mat detail = img - base;
      base.release();
      Mat kernel = Mat::ones(7, 7, CV_32FC1)*(1 / 49);
      Mat conved, wd;
      filter2D(lum, conved, -1, kernel);
      wd = (conved - 0.5).mul(conved - 0.5) / (-2 * sig_d*sig_d);
      exp(wd, wd);
      W_D.push_back(wd);
      D.push_back(detail);
  }

  Mat wb_s = W_B[0].clone(), wd_s = W_D[0].clone();
  for (int i = 1; i < pme.size(); i++) {
      add(wb_s, W_B[i], wb_s);
      add(wd_s, W_D[i], wd_s);
  }

  Mat dst = Mat::zeros(pme[0].size(), CV_32FC3);
  for (int i = 0; i < pme.size(); i++) {
      Mat wb, wd;
      divide(W_B[i], wb_s, wb);
      divide(W_D[i], wd_s, wd);

      cvtColor(wd, wd, COLOR_GRAY2RGB);
      multiply(wd, D[i], wd);
      wd *= alpha;

      multiply(wb, B[i], wb);
      cvtColor(wb, wb, COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

      dst += wd + wb;

      W_B[i].release(); W_D[i].release(); D[i].release(); B[i].release();
  }
  res = dst.clone();
}
```

Comment: Post also c++ code

Comment: Added code as requested. But question still remains why is OpenCV's function slower in C++ than Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just realised that I was facing this problem due to running my code in debug mode. When I switched to release mode the performance was similar to that of python. I would leave this here incase someone runs in to similar problem making same mistake as me.